# if i want use mongodb 3.0 which version of pymongo i should choose

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Today our DBA give me 3 Mongo ip, but the Mongo's version is 3.0.2, my PyMongo's version is 2.6, and i tried to connect them, but i failed. And i cannot upgrade my PyMongo's version cause other people also use it and they need not connect Mongo 3.0. If i upgrade it, i do not know will effect what, maybe let all server down.
So i want to know if i can use PyMongo 2.6 to connect to the Mongo 3.0. 
Thanks.

```
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: command SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', u'quiz_w'), ('nonce', u'ee64d2f8018e802c'), ('key', u'50537b45b229b959b695b7d2ff3d9c4c')]) failed: auth failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`pymongo` Change Log](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/changelog.html#changes-in-version-2-8), you should use `pymongo` >=2.8  in case of MongoDB 3.0:

> Version 2.8 is a major release that provides full support for MongoDB 3.0 and fixes a number of bugs.

Though, I'd use the latest stable `pymongo` which is now 3.0.3.

Comment: Shouldn't they use PyMongo 3 (the latest PyMongo version)?

Comment: @vaultah well, pymongo versions are not in sync with mongodb versions. In terms of pymongo 3 does not mean it's for mongodb 3..the OP may start with pymongo 2.8, but, sure, it's recommended to use the latest pymongo version, which is now 3.0.3. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, i ask one of my workmate just now, he is use Mongo 3.0 too, he said he put the Pymongo 2.8 in his project ,change the path and  import it, this will not affect others, maybe i will use it like him.